# Using html tags with id+numbers to find them in jQuery

Tags: jquery, loops

Having an html code like this:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor=yellow>LED #1</td>
        <td id=led0 bgcolor=red>ON</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor=yellow>LED #2</td>
        <td id=led1 bgcolor=red>ON</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor=yellow>LED #3</td>
        <td id=led2 bgcolor=red>ON</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td bgcolor=yellow>LED #4</td>
        <td id=led3 bgcolor=red>ON</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>number 1</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>number 2</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <button>number 3</button>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

I would like to achieve something like this:

```
$('button').click(function() {
  var index = $("button").index(this);   
 // alert(index);
  $("#led[index]").html('<div style="background:#cccccc" >OFF</div>');

  
});
```

In words: I want to detect the button pressed (which is already working) and then modify the html code of the td element with `id="led[index]"` and using the variable `"index"` to find the right led number.

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I went one step further and made it so that you can toggle `ON` or `OFF`.  Your main issue is that you did not concatenate `index`, this should be done like so `+ index +`.  I used the following jQuery code:

```
$('button').click(function() {
var index = $("button").index(this);   
// alert(index);
  // You must concatenate index with "+"
  if ($("#led"+index+":contains('ON')").length > 0)
    $("#led"+index).html("OFF").css("background-color", "red");
  else if ($("#led"+index+":contains('OFF')").length > 0)
    $("#led"+index).html("ON").css("background-color", "green");
});
```

I also made a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Hy3Fa/) so that you can see it work.

You can put whatever HTML you want where the `ON` or `OFF` is changed.

Answer (score 2):

Cancatenate the following way:

```
$("#led" + index);
```

Answer (score 0):

You would want to use `$(this).attr("id");` and then concatenate the index to the `#led` id

```
        $('button').click(function() {
          var index = $(this).attr("id");
          $("#led" + index).html('<div id="led'+index+'" style="background:red" >ON</div>');

        // code
    });
```

HTML:

```
<button id="someID">
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make two edits to your code:

First, you need use the `attr('id')` method to get the index.

Secondly, you need to concatenate the index onto your jQuery selector.

```
$('button').click(function() {
    var index = $(this).attr('id');   
    $("#led"+index).html('<div id="led'+index+'" style="background:red" >ON</div>');
});
```